# Как правильно задать условие в PHP?

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Циклом While из БД выводятся  строки id,Vid,Name.

Как правильно задать условие, при котором будет выполнятся мой кусок кода (например: Echo "МЯУ") при каждом совпадении $row['name'] с "ИВАН".

Почему то выдает МЯУ при любом значении.
Не выдает только при пустом значении.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
do
{


     printf("<div>".$row['name']  .$row['vid'] .$row['id']."</div>);

 if ($row['name'] ="ИВАН") echo "МЯУ";  
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: а ты уже знаешь как пишется знак сравнения или еще нет?

Comment: Я чайник=) Пробовал ==  В результате -даже при совпадении ничего не выводится

Comment: `$row['name'] ="ИВАН"` у вас тут опечатка, либо если вы не знаете еще действительно про сравнения, [почитайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Вот тут `."</div>);` забыли закрыть кавычку. Вот тут `$row['name'] ="ИВАН"` вы не сравниваете, а присваиваете. Да и сравнивать было бы логично внутри цикла, а не до него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($row['name'] == "ИВАН") echo "МЯУ";
    printf("<div>".$row['name']  .$row['vid'] .$row['id']."</div>");
}
```

Comment: Нет, опишите задачу более подробно. Зачем вообще `printf` используется? Если решение подошло, отметьте, пожалуйста, его принятым.